# Store DPI info in EPS image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, dpi, eps

I’m trying to store DPI information in an Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) image with Pillow library.

For instance:

```
from PIL import Image

size = 650, 827
path = 'grey.eps'

image = Image.new('L', size, color='grey')
image.save(path, dpi=(300, 300))
```

But I can’t retrieve this info on reading:

```
image = Image.open(path)
dpi = image.info['dpi']
print(dpi)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'dpi'
```

Is it possible to have DPI information in EPS images or is it a limitation to the Pillow library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can't store 'dpi information' in an EPS. The DPI of the image depends on how its printed.

If you take an image 100x100 samples and print it on a 1 inch square, then the dpi of the image is 100 dpi. If I take the same image and print it on a 2 inch square, then the dpi of the image is 50 dpi.

One of the points of an EPS file is that you can rescale the EPS to fit the content of the page, so the dpi of the image depends entirely on what scaling is applied to it.

EPS is not a simple bitmap format, like say TIFF, PostScript is a complete programming language and includes primitives for all sorts of vector drawing operations, as well as bitmaps.

Comment: Do you mean that DPI information is not relevant to EPS images?

Comment: +1. in graphic printing lingo, eps is a vector not bitmap (raster) image. although, i'm not sure what `image.info` does there, is it just storing metadata to a mutable data sets? or is the purpose just for _updating_ a fixed set of data?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE There's no need for DPI in EPS files in practical sense, since EPS as pointed out, is a vector file, it will accomodate any size in every which way it's instructed to without degradation of quality, unlike bitmap images. Bitmap images uses DPI [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch](Dot Per Inch) for physical printing softwares, so changing the size of print affects its density, hence the quality limit. see http://superluxescreenprinting.com/2009/07/28/vector-vs-bitmap-explained/